# admin.google.com redirects me to apps.google.com with limited functionality

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

For over ten years I have been using Google Mail for domain (was free back then) and I used Google Admin console to manage accounts, MX records, etc.

However, now I'm trying to login to `admin.google.com` and it redirects me to `apps.google.com` ("G Suite Hub") and I can't even manage users or anything from there. Just install / uninstall some apps (mostly useless). Support is silent, since they only support paid accounts.

Is there any chance to regain control over Admin console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are being redirected from admin.google.com to apps.google.com is because you aren't using an account with admin privileges.

There is an official troubleshooter that could help gain access to the admin panel : [Can't sign in to the Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6335621?hl=en)

Comment: Yes, although I fixed this issue half a year ago, that was the case

Answer (score 1):

The only way for me to resolve this was: clear your cookies/cache.